# Right-click menus VS Buttons for Desktop Win/Mac application

Tags: buttons, right-click

I'd like to know what is the current trend when it comes to options in a list of items.

Is it better to have a right-click menu like this:
[image: Right-click menu]

Or, buttons at the bottom of the list which enable/disable based on the items like this:

[image: Buttons at the bottom]

Thanks

Comment: Right-click menus are secondary, shortcut, actions. It should never be your primary form of interaction.

Comment: Then, would opening or editing an item be considered a secondary action?

Comment: Rephrasing: Right-click menu's should never be the **only** way to perform the action. So, there should be a way to open/edit an item somewhere else in the UI -- the right-click menu is a shortcut to that action.

Answer (score 2):

Why not both? Experienced users could use **right click** in order to get the options that they are looking for. And less experienced users might **look for the option** that fits them. In this way, **you support both groups of people.**

Talking about trends, I can give my insight about web applications only. Although I believe that it can be used in more cases than web. This example is taken from Dropbox.

[image: dropbox]

Comment: If I have both options, wouldn't this make the UI packed? 

The example from Dropbox is an option I considered but not per item as the image shows but for the whole list

Comment: Why do you think that it would make it packed? Since one option happens on the right click and one when you click the button.If you had to keep one option, I would suggest that you keep the visible one. But I don't see why it can harm keeping both. (Design remark: I would advise you to add clear labels under the buttons as well. )

Comment: If you have 6-7 actions, then you need 6-7 buttons. Wouldn't this pack the UI?

About the labels: there is a hint when the user hovers the buttons

Comment: maybe you could show the user the most used actions and not so used actions under: "See more"

Comment: If you _haven't_ got room for 6-7 (or whatever) buttons, then right-click may be your only choice. @JohnKouraklis I think what Dimitra is saying is that if you **have** got room, use both (because allowing right-click takes up _no more_ room). Also, "hovers" are better than nothing, but without labels, you might have to hover over several buttons to find the one you want.